# How to insert phone numbers from multiple tables to single contact table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

When I a have different table like teachers, students... I want to insert those phone number to single contact table.

1. Teacher Table
2. Student Table
3. Contact Table

How to create its relationship of Contact table with those table without redundancy of Foreign key?

Comment: Foreign keys are the least redundant way of storing data relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there be no overlap between teachers and students, you could do an insert of the union of the two tables

```sql
INSERT INTO Contact (name, phone)
SELECT name, phone FROM Teacher
UNION ALL
SELECT name, phone FROM Student;
```

You might want to also create a new column in `Contact` which keeps track of the type of contact.  In that case, use something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO Contact (name, phone, type)
SELECT name, phone, 'teacher' FROM Teacher
UNION ALL
SELECT name, phone, 'student' FROM Student;
```

Comment: If one teacher and student have the same name then?

Comment: How to know this phone number belongs to which one student or teacher?

Comment: Ideally you should have a single person table, in which each teacher and student gets a unique primary key.  But, the second half of my answer also fixes this, unless two teachers (or two students) happen to also have the same name.